# Excel: generate specific length string reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've found some tools that can do what I want, but despite trying various options I can't work out how to put them in my existing formula!

I'm trying to generate an invoice reference number, which would look like 'ABC000012' - with the first row being ABC000001 and increasing in number as each row is added. I can currently generate 'ABC1' and so on, but can't work out how to add the preceding 0s.

I'm currently using CONCATENATE as follows:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),,CONCATENATE("ABC",(ROW(1:1))))
```

What do I need to add to this, and where, in order to get the references I'm looking for?

I'm also happy to be advised that I should change the whole formula if there's something different that will work better

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"","ABC"&RIGHT("000000"&ROW(1:1),6))
```

This is based off Scott Craner's answer.  The difference is that is will limit the number of digits in your invoice to 6 characters.  if you want it to always be 8 characters long change the 6 to an 8 and increase the number of 0 between the " ".  Alternatively you could also do:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"","ABC"&RIGHT(rept(0,6)&ROW(1:1),6))
```

In the above formula to change the number of digits n the invoice number, you would need to change both 6's

Caveat:

If there is a blank cell in the middle of your list, that number will be skipped for each blank cell.  To avoid this, you will need a different counting method than row(1:1).

Answer (score 2):

Use TEXT() to set the preceding 0:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",CONCATENATE("ABC",TEXT(ROW(1:1),"000000")))
```

[image]